# How to access a form in a custom form handler

Tags: php, drupal, open-source, content-management-system

I'm using the following logic to add a custom handler to a form that's defined by another module. I'm trying to do additional processing on the form data.

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_additional_submit_handler';
  }
}
```

Of course I define my own handler called `my_additional_submit_handler`

```
function my_additional_submit_handler(){

}
```

but how do I pass the form and its values to my custom handler? I tried passing &$form, but could not access it in the custom handler with dsm. Is there a special syntax to pass in arguments with the custom form handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried this ? It should work as expected:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {  
  if($form_id=="your_form"){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_mysubmit';
  }
}

function mymodule_form_mysubmit($form, &$form_state){
    // $form is your entire form object
    // $form_state should be your submitted data
}
```

Comment: have you tried to clear the cache ? Did your function work without the parameter?
Also I just read this, maybe you could try the approach here as well
http://drupal.org/node/144132#custom-params

Comment: This should work. If it doesn't, and because dsm("string") doesn't work neither, I suspect your are not altering the form at all. Check your $form_id in your hook_form_alter.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the data in `$form_state['values']['fieldName']`? Also, as iKid mensioned in his code sample you need the args `$form and $form_state` in your handler function.